# back-end python flask code is not returning negative response to front-end ajax code, Its only returning success response

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, flask

I am trying to work on this below code on getting Success and Failure Ajax response from the back-end Python Flask code.

The back-end code is returning only success ajax response and only the front-end success ajax code is getting triggered and not the failure code even if the back-end code is returning failure response to the front-end

I tried sending the negative failure response from back-end code by entering the wrong OTP but still, the front-end success method is getting triggered which is alert with success message

```
function myFunction() {

    $.ajax({
            url: '/ValidateOTP',
            type: 'POST',
            data:JSON.stringify( $('#OTP').val()),
            contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
            success: function(response){
                alert("Success")

            },
            error: function(response){
                    alert("Failure")

            }
        });
};
```

```py
@app.route('/ValidateOTP', methods=['GET','POST'])
def ValidateOTP():
    OTP = request.get_json()
    otpinstant=session['OTPINSTA']
    if otpinstant==OTP:
        Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
        s = Session()
        query = s.query(ElectricMan).filter_by(email_id=email).first()
        result=query.first_name
        if result:
            session['logged_in'] = True
            return home()

        else:
            return home()
    else:
        return home()
```

Comment: your run `return home()` in every situation so you could use only one `return home()`  at the end of function.

Comment: check what you have in `home()` because it decides what will be send to browser.

Comment: Thanks furas for your answer!!!  can you please help me in sending the success or failure acknowledgement to the front-end?

Comment: the reason for using home() in all the situation is to check the code. i will change the code if this current problem is resolved

Comment: it is not problem that you use ``home()` so many times. But you should check what you do in `home()` because it returns value which later `return home()` sends to AJAX

Comment: frankly, as I know `error:` in JavaScript doesn't check if you send negative result but if there was no problem to connect with server. In `success:` you should checke what result you get in response - positive or negative. ie `alert(response)` instead of `alert("Success")`